# How to set a div to nested inside another div and to fill within parent div with auto adjustable height and weight

Tags: html, css

I have created a sample layout. [image: sample layout] 
In this layout, i want that `<div>` that is highlighted in blue color to be filled within brown color `flex`. and it should be auto adjustable according to the browser window size. The HTML code of the brown color layout looks like below.

```
<div layout="column" style="height:100vh;">
<div flex="20" class="bg-brown"> //height of this div is less than 100vh
  <div class="bg-blue"> //width and height os this div should be same as brown color highlighted div ()
    <div class="unselectable"> hello swipe this </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have already tried some of the answers in Stackoverflow. But non of them worked. I think that is because I use Angular Material

I already tried this:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div flex="20" class="bg-brown" style="height:100%">
  <div class="bg-blue" style="height:100%">
    <div class="unselectable">hello swipe this</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try `body, html{
    height:100%;
}`

Comment: still it's the same

Comment: Find the complete code [here] (http://codepen.io/Srinesh/pen/PzZLLN)
for some reason this link can not be included inside the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `div.bg-brown` to have `display: flex; flex-flow: column;`, and the `bg-blue` to have `flex: 1`. It should do the tricks.

For example: http://jsbin.com/cozukizego/edit?html,output

Comment: I can not set height and weight to the `bg-brown`. i have used angular `flex="20"` to set the width and height is the default as defined in angular material

Comment: You don't have to. As long as the `bg-brown` element has the right height, the `bg-blue` will have the same height.

Comment: but. that doesn't make any change
[find the full code in the link](http://codepen.io/Srinesh/pen/PzZLLN)

Comment: You need to add `flex: 1` also to the `div` that wraps `bg-blue` like so: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jrWJRL